# Newest Chrome 85 removing 3rd party cookie with SameSite=None and secure

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

The latest version of Chrome (85.0.4183.83) is removing my 3rd party cookies, although they are set as SameSite=None; secure; - how can this be, and am I the only one experiencing this?

They are also HttpOnly, if that matters, and it happens when setting the cookie through a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Are we talking web page, Chrome Extension or..?

Comment: Chrome Extension actually. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 85 seems to be removing 3rd party cookies set by Chrome Extensions, regardless of SameSite attribute. It doesn't seem to be documented, so it may be unintended.